# ICU Byte Order Mark (BOM)

Tags: c++, unicode, endianness, icu, byte-order-mark

I am using ICU's ustdio functions to write a UnicodeString object to a file in a range of encodings, however it doesn't appear to prepend the BOM.

My Code:

```
void write_file(const char* filename, UnicodeString &str) {

    UFILE* f = u_fopen(filename, "w", NULL, "UTF-16 LE");
    u_file_write(str.getTerminatedBuffer(), str.length() + 1, f);
    u_fclose(f);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    UnicodeString str(L"ΠαρθένωνΗ");

    write_file("test.txt", str);

    return 0;
}
```

The file encoding does swap when I change LE to BE, however there is no BOM, the output file in a hex editor is:

```
A0 03 B1 03  C1 03 B8 03  AD 03 BD 03  C9 03 BD 03  97 03 00 00
```

NOTE: If I set the codepage as "UTF-16", there is a BOM, however once I manually specify the endianness it disappears.

Alternatively is there a way I could write the UnicodeString to a file with a BOM?

Comment: Well, makes sense doesn't it?  The BOM is there to help the reader of the file to discover the endian-ness.  So it doesn't matter what your machine writes by default.  If you use "UTF-16" then anybody can read it.

Comment: This behavior is mandated by the Unicode standard: you must not use a BOM if you have some higher-level protocol (in this case, your C code) to indicate the endianness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just guessing, the "UTF-16 LE" and "UTF-16 BE" were intended to be used when the byte order was well specified and the BOM would not be necessary in the context where the file would be used.

You should be able to write your own [BOM character `'\ufeff'`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the file.

Comment: You are exactly right. You should write your own BOM character if you want one under utf-16 LE or BE.   Note that the "utf-16" converter writes a BOM and also '''detects''' the incoming BOM and so utf-16 can read either LE or BE, if there's a BOM.   

    u_fputc(0x00feff,f);

Answer (score 2):

`u_fputc(0x00feff,f);`

will do it.